# How to filter between junk exe files and workable exe files

Tags: c#

I've got all the exe files now but the thing is x.x it's giving me all the EXEs, and now I have to filter between executables which run the required app and all junk executables.
Like in Internet Explorer folder I have:

C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieinstal.exe
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ielowutil.exe
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe

but I just want the `iexplorer.exe` file and for me, all others are junk. Is there any way to filter between these?

```
List<string> path = new List<string>();
List<string> realPaths = new List<string>();

try
{
    path.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    path.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    foreach (string item in path)
    {
        string[] parse = item.Split('\\');
        if (parse.Contains("Common Files")
            || parse.Contains("IIS") || parse.Contains("Microsoft Help Viewer")
            || parse.Contains("Microsoft SQL Server") || parse.Contains("Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition")
            || parse.Contains("Microsoft Sync Framework") || parse.Contains("Microsoft Synchronization Services")
            || parse.Contains("Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0") || parse.Contains("Microsoft.NET") || parse.Contains("MSBuild")
            || parse.Contains("Reference Assemblies") || parse.Contains("Windows Defender") || parse.Contains("Windows NT")
            || parse.Contains("HTML Help Workshop") || parse.Contains("Microsoft Analysis Services") || parse.Contains("Microsoft ASP.NET")
            || parse.Contains("Microsoft F#") || parse.Contains("Microsoft Games for Windows - LIVE") || parse.Contains("Microsoft SDKs")
            || parse.Contains("Microsoft Silverlight") || parse.Contains("Microsoft Visual Studio 8") || parse.Contains("Microsoft XNA")
            || parse.Contains("Mozilla Maintenance Service"))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            realPaths.Add(item);
        }
    }
    foreach (string item in realPaths)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "junk". The other executables aren't "junk"; they're apparently just not the ones you're looking for. If you want only `iexplorer.exe`, then just look for `iexplorer.exe` - you need to filter them yourself. You've asked for all `.exe` files, and you're getting exactly what you wanted. How is your code supposed to tell what you think is "junk"? You have to write the code to do so.

Comment: thats what i m asking that if anyone can modify it :S and i wrote/define junk there as the files which i not wanted :P

Comment: Well, you haven't defined "junk", either to us or in your code. Your code says "Give me a list of all files with the .exe extension in these folders", and you've gotten exactly what you asked. You have code that parses those results. What have you tried to do to also parse and eliminate what you consider "junk"? If you can't tell us what makes it "junk", how are we supposed to tell you how to remove it? So far you've said "There are three executable files in this one folder, and I only want one of them". Based on that, your fix is "If it's not iexplorer.exe, don't include it". That's easy.

Comment: i want exe files of all the softwares installed on my pc and only the executables which makes the software run directly like internet explorer wil run from iexplorer.exe and google chrome will run from chrome.exe excel run from excel.exe word run from msword.exe etc
my search returns me in total around 1k+ exe files 
i have an idea too but i dont know how it works 
when ever we install any software(in Program Files folder) it gets its entry in start menu thats mean windows makes list of these kind of exe files along with their paths somewhr i jst want that thing

Comment: if u can generaly tell me whr it makes that file i can grab it off :P

Comment: OK. One more try: **How does your code know what you want**? You told it **give me all files with the .exe extension**. How do you tell it **I don't really mean "all". I really mean "only these files"**?

Comment: ya thats what i want help with that how i tell it in my code..

Comment: i dont want to write name of 500+ exe files is there any way to do this in some different way?

Comment: @WaqarMuhammad All the exe files are executable, the code can not know which file executes the stuff you want. Your best bet is to choose the largest file among those exe files, but it has only maybe 50% probability of choosing the right file.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's really no perfect way to do what you're trying to do; all executables are basically "created equal."

What exactly do you hope to achieve, and why?

Perhaps your goal is to show only executables that the user is likely to want to run? If that were your goal, your question could be: *"How can I tell which executables the user has used before or is likely to directly invoke in the future?"*

If that was the question, then you could come up with a *heuristic* approach to try to solve the problem. Your algorithm could do things like look at the shortcuts on the desktop and Start menu, as well as the registry-based list of programs registered in *AppPaths* and similar locations to try to infer which executables are more or less likely to be run. It wouldn't be perfect, of course, but sometimes an imperfect approach is better than nothing.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You've provided no solution, but have asked several questions asking for a clarification of the problem. I'm not sure how this is an answer. Can you edit to actually provide one? If not, this is an extended comment.

Comment: ya @EricLaw that is my question how can i achieve this task? i am making a program which should get all the programs installed on a local machine so when user wants to launch some application it will directly say to my application that "launch chrome" or Launch Iexplorer or Launch Media player etc and my application will search for the program and then execute the program (its a speech based app so user is directly communicating with it by speaking )

Comment: WaqarMuhammad: Based on your description, I think your best approach is to scan the user's Start Menu and use the programs listed there as the list of applications exposed via voice input. Going the other direction (scanning for executables and trying to guess which ones matter) is unlikely to yield results.

Comment: @KenWhite: I proposed one possible approach for attempting to solve the problem, while noting that the problem, as currently phrased, was not tractable.