# How To Compare two strings on Percentage Basis

Tags: c#

I want to compare two strings on percentage basis
like i have this

```
Player and wmplayer
Manager and IDMan
Mail and WINMail
Explorer and iexplorer
```

Any Help Please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344320/comparing-strings-with-tolerance

Comment: You've given inputs but not told us what your expected outputs are?

Comment: i want that at how much % both strings matching

and if u know that how i can differentiate between main exe file in a folder which run program between different exe files in same folder?

Comment: or u can review this and get more understanding of my needs :P

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808657/how-to-filter-between-junk-exe-files-and-workable-exe-files

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make use of a library such as [ScoreSharp](https://github.com/bltavares/ScoreSharp). It is designed to do fuzzy matching to find similarities between strings.